# How to check if an order number exists in woocommerce?

Tags: woocommerce

In my WooCommerce store, I have an input field where I want the user to enter the order number. When validating this field, I need to check if that order **number** actually exists in WooCommerce.

From [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/314479/how-to-check-if-woocommerce-order-number-equals-to-post-id?rq=1), it seems like the WooCommerce *order_number* might not always be the same as the *order_id* (which is always the same as the *post_id*).

So I can't use *wc_get_order($the_order)* function since [the documentation](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-wc_get_order.html#69-84) states that it wants the *post_id* in the *$the_order* parameter.

I can't find a specific function to get the order by the **order number** (neither in the documentation nor the code in github).

I'm fairly new to WooCommerce, so maybe I am missing something. Is there a way to do this at all? Or is the *wc_get_order* mis-documented?

I've done a lot of googling and searching here on stack overflow, but I really can't find the answer to this! Any help is appreciated.

PS: I suppose I could get all orders and loop through them one by one checking if the number matches, but I was hoping to find a simpler solution to this :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason you're struggling to find anything about this in the documentation is because WooCommerce has no native concept of an order number. The ID is the order number.

What store owners tend to find however is that order IDs don't increase sequentially. There can be a large jump in ID between one order and the next because of the way WordPress handles posts. Often users will install a plugin to address that. It's those plugins that introduce the differentiation between order IDs and what they refer to as the order number.

Here's an example of one such plugin: https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-sequential-order-numbers/

Included in the documentation is an example of how to find an order by its number. If you have one of these plugins installed, you'll simply need to lookup how the plugin in question resolves numbers to IDs.

Comment: Thanks, that really clarified the issue. So (just to make sure I understood this 100% correctly) if I don't have any plugins installed that mess with the Order ID, then I can trust that when I pass the order number (of an existing order) to wc_get_order() it will always find the order. Is that correct?

Comment: @MairaBay yup, it's only when you're using a plugin to deal with order number sequencing that you run into any divergence. If you don't have anything like that running, you can trust that the number given to the customer is the same as order / post ID.

Comment: awesome! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 7):

You may try this if statement to see if given ID (number) is an Order Number or not:

```
function is_it_a_shop_order($givenNumber)
{   
    if(get_post_type($givenNumber) == "shop_order")
    {
        echo "yes this is a valid order number";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "no go away";
    }
}
```

Wordpress stores all posts (pages, orders, products etc.) in wp_posts table and orders are stored with post type named "shop_order".

I tested the code. I hope this will help you. Have a good day.

Answer (score 0):

Send the order number through the wc_get_order call. If the returned array is empty, the order number does not exist.

```
$bOrderExists = DoesOrderExist($OrderNumber);

function DoesOrderExist($OrderNumber)
  {
  $orderq   = wc_get_order($OrderNumber);
  if(empty($orderq))
    return 0;

return 1;
 }
```